# Can lightsabers ever bend?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

[Mandalorian Crushgaunt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Crushgaunt) is so resistant to lightsabers, that they can hold/stop lightsaber blades (source: comments on [Why did Vader choose to take potshots from Han](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/why-did-darth-vader-choose-to-take-shots-from-han-solo)).

Does that mean with lightsaber resistance armor, that a lightsaber blade can be bent? Perhaps its length would be truncated if thrust into Mandalorian Crushgaunt?

Comment: Sure they can. Haven't you ever gotten your [Schwartz twisted](http://content7.flixster.com/question/40/03/40/4003405_std.jpg)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**: To answer the subject line of the question (as opposed to the substance of the body of it, which the original answer did): **Yes and No**.

No, a regular lightsaber's blade can't typically bend (at least around known solid materials that don't generate super-intensive magnetic fields) - see the original answer below.

Yes, a lightsaber can **theoretically** bend if constructed for the purpose - more specifically, a version of lightsaber called "[Lightwhip](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightwhip)" had a flexible blade by design.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

No, Mandalorian Crushgaunts **did NOT "bend"** the lightsaber blades, but instead absorbed the energy of the blade and/or the blaster bolt.

Mandalorian Crushgaunts are made using Mandalorian Iron (aka [Beskar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beskar#Beskar)).

Once processed, Beskar becomes a very hard metal, capable of absorbing many hits from blasters and even lightsabers.

Please note that this is different from **[Cortosis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cortosis)** ore (and Cortosis gauntlets made from it), which actually shorted out the lightsaber's power supply, as opposed to merely blocking the blade.

Answer (score 15):

Short answer: yes, and in some cases they are even designed to.

Longer answer: Lady Lumiya, an Extended Universe character, was trained as a Sith by Darth Vader somewhere in the general timeline of ESB/RotJ (violating the Rule of Two, but this rule was commonly broken by both Palpatine and Vader during their time). She was on a pilgrimage to the ancient Sith world Ziost when the Death Star was destroyed, and as such became the last living Sith after the Empire's defeat. From Darth Vader, she had acquired a shard of Kaiburr crystal, a very powerful Force-focusing material, and used it to build a highly flexible lightsaber weapon called a "[lightwhip](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightwhip)".

Lumiya's weapon, though rare, was not unique; lightwhips are seen in several forms in the hands of Force practitioners through the Extended Universe history, mostly in the hands of Sith, Nightsisters and other Dark Side Force users (though Obi-Wan Kenobi is a notable exception, having fashioned and used a lightwhip for a time during the Clone Wars).

Lightwhips were generally used not for any great power inherent in the design, but because they were rare and thus unfamiliar to one's opponent; in a battle to the death against a weapon you've never seen before, you learn quickly or die.

Below is Sith Lady Githany, the first known lightwhip user around 1000BBY.

[image: Githany, bareheaded but otherwise in armour of overlapping plates and segments, wields a lightwhip in her right hand. She holds it overhead and behind her, and it trails at least a couple of metres behind her, looking very much like a bullwhip.]

Lumiya's lightwhip is similar in theory, but has multiple "strands", to form a cat-o-nine-tails-style weapon:

[image: Lumiya stands facing outward, both arms out to her sides. The lightwhip is in her right hand with multiple strands arcing across in front of her.]

Comment: Interesting +1. Although I'm questioning whether a straight blade could be caught and then bent.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question in your title, rather than the specific scenario of using lightsaber-resistant materials, yes, it appears that the blade of a lightsaber can be bent using the Force.

Borrowing from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11103/1359), the novelization of *The Revenge of the Sith* describes the following from the battle between Mace Windu and Darth Sidious:

> Palpatine still made no move to defend himself from Skywalker; instead he ramped up the lightning bursting from his hands, bending the fountain of Mace's blade back toward the Korun Master's face.
>
> [...]
>
> This was beyond Vaapad; he had no strengt left to fight against his own blade.
>
> [...]
>
> Mace's blade bent so close to his face that he was choking
> on ozone. "Anakin, he's too strong for me—"

Comment: This is the best answer. The question isn't asking about light-whips, but lightsabers.

Comment: I just re-read this answer and am unsure - did this mean that the blade was bending as a blade, or that the angle of the whole blade was bent as Mace's hand was bent, ala pressing a real metal blade into your opponent's face?

Comment: @DVK the quality of the writing isn't exceptional,  but because it specifies *the fountain* of the blade being bent, it sounds more like the former to me than the latter, although you are right that it is not 100% clear.

Comment: @Beofett -  may be worth asking as a separate question?

Comment: @DVK I'm not sure how I'd word it without being a dupe of this one?

Answer (score 4):

Lightsabers have their blade contained by a magnetic field, as implied here in this photo:

[image: Light saber schematic]

This job is done by the [Blade emitter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_emitter)

> The emitter possessed the magnetic ring that created the field that contained the plasma of the blade and arced it back to the lightsaber for re-conversion back into electricity.

Theoretically a high enough magnetic field would disrupt the one from the blade emitter and cause the plasma to bend, if not break the loop and short out the lightsaber.

Unfortunately I could not find a reference for this picture so I am unsure of it's canonicity.

Comment: I count about four typical capacitors, two resistors and an LED in the energy modulation circuit. If I can find the crystals, I should be able to construct my own!

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

Wave it around in a non-homogeneous gravity field. You will see it wobbling around like rubber due to relativistic effects.

Comment: The effect from a non-homogenous gravity field would be so small, compared to the containment field I'd imagine it would be negligable, unless you thought the 'saber into a black hole. Plus it would only move in a certain frame of reference....

Comment: I didn't specify how inhomogeneous the field must be. If the effect isn't strong for you (note that OP did not ask for a strong bend, just some degree), just increase the inhomogeneity (i.e. rotate faster around your own axis).