# Is it ever viewable in canon where a Sith lightsaber breaks a Jedi's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Is it viewable anywhere in canon where a Sith's lightsaber disrupts a Jedi's lightsaber blade?

Comment: I guess two knockoff lightsaber rings getting convoluted doesn't count? From what I remember, I haven't seen any single instance of a lightsaber "blade" being broken, bent, or disrupted in some way (excluding incidents of the actual device failing, e.g. due to being cut). Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: I don't believe the blade could be *broken*... It is not solid, it is directional light... What is breakable is the actual grip device, which breaks a lot in the prequel movies

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11663/can-lightsabers-ever-bend

Comment: Also, tons of materials could break the blade (cortosis ore, Mandalorian iron, Foreworm armor o Eol Sha)

Comment: @Mario- I got the idea from Star Wars where it says a sith crystal is powerful enough to disrupt a jedi's blade. Do you even Star Wars?

Answer (score 6):

According to Legends canon: yes.

> In fact, synth-crystal blades were so powerful that they had the rare potential to "break the blade" of standard lightsabers by overloading the energy matrix and instantly burning out the other lightsaber. Though this happened extremely rarely, it was a known and frightening possibility in combat (*Source: [Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Synthetic_lightsaber_crystal), referencing "**Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force**"*)

I'll try to post the exact quote from the source when I'm home.

Comment: Is it viewable  anywhere in the movies or clone wars series of this happening?

Comment: @Jwad - Movies, no. Clone wars, need to dig more. But likely no.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't recall it in the movies, I just recently watched the entire Clone Wars series and didn't remember that happening. Is the power short actual G Lucas canon or EU?

Comment: The guides are EU