# Did Palpatine plan to confront and kill four Jedi Masters including Mace Windu himself, or did it happen by chance?

Tags: star-wars

I cannot make my mind up on this.

He reveals himself to Anakin, and allows Anakin to leave. As a result, the greatest swordsman in the order and some (apparently) gifted others rush to face him.

Fortunately for him, he is able to kill three with ease. Then he is part of an epic duel that people debate he may or may not have ['thrown'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/did-palpatine-intentionally-lose-to-mace-windu) - but did he design that situation, killing Windu personally and putting Anakin in an impossible situation that finally turned him, or was this out of his control? Did he really want to face Windu and have a battle that most feel was a defeat and the reason for his disfigurement?

(Related prompts, but all part of this question: Did he feel only he could kill Windu? Did he want to kill him personally? Did he feel Order 66 wouldn’t work if Windu was out there? Was this very precise situation the only way Anakin would fully turn?)

To summarise: Did Palpatine want or need to face Windu, or was it a dangerous risk?

Comment: He used the arrest attempt to convince the Republic that jedi wanted to assassinate him which gave the grounds for Order 66.

Comment: And he was trying really quite hard to kill Windu before Anakin arrived.

Comment: "Everything is proceeding **as I have foreseen**".

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Isn't that in RotJ?

Comment: @Richard - I'm wondering if Palpatine planned the confrontation from a while back, not whether or not he chose to try to stick his lightsabre in Mace Windu when confronted!

Comment: While I have no evidence one way or another, I'd suggest that Palpatine was probably more concerned that Yoda was away than that Windu was around. The same could be said for Kenobi, since that was the one person Anakin might've still listened to. If the two biggest threats to your plan are out of town, I'd think that would be the perfect time to move forward.

Comment: @ThruGog - Yep. But I am extrapolating :)

Comment: I have a side-theory that if Anakin had for some reason not shown up, Palpatine's backup plan was to try to turn Mace instead. Mace was already pretty close to the dark, and his fighting style of Vaapad was based around channeling that darkness. Getting him to fight in that style for a prolonged period might have turned him.

Comment: This might have been answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158092/75000)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but i would say that no, he probably did want Anakin to see, that he would be outnumbered or something, so Anakin had to help him. That said, he could have ''lost'' on purpose to any jedi Anakin told of him. Big risk, becose if Windu would have accompanied by Joda, his plot would have failed. But he could not have known who was coming for sure. (Ofcourse he would have chosen a moment when Obiwan or Joda were least likely to interfere, Obi in same room would have easily changed Anis mind) (Sorry if my english s**ks!)

Comment: Sidious knew that Yoda was on Kashyyyk and that Obi-Wan was on Utapau. Windu felt that he had to act quickly, so there would be no way for him to take either Yoda or Obi-Wan. Sidious revealed himself at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

There were no guards at the entrance, and Palpatine was suspiciously alone in office. Compare that with duel vs Yoda, where both two guards and Mas Amedda were present at the beginning. This leaves us to conclude that Palpatine carefully orchestrated duel against 4 Jedi Masters in a controlled setting and without unnecessary witnesses.